# React redux same store values not getting in anthor component if am using router

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

If a component containing  components is exported with a Redux connect wrapper non of the components mapped to those routes components are rendered. Let's say you have

```
<BrowserRouter>
 <App />
</BrowserRouter>
```

and App looks like:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/Test1" component={Test1}/>
          <Route path="/Test2" component={Test2} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

if am updating store using mapDispatchToProps in Home(first component ) and trying to get same updated store values in Test1 (second component) using mapStateToProps

```
Eg: export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Test1);
```

But am getting store array as 0 in Test1 component.

I want like if am update store values using mapDispatchToProps  in component1 , I need the updated store in component2 mapStateToProps.

I have tried many things but it not helpful so here am posting for help ,thanks advance .

Comment: did you add `provider` with `store`

Comment: yes ,in app,js I have provide the provider with store.

Comment: can you share a codesandbox with the problem?

Comment: If you could provide code of store and reducer would be easy to help

Comment: sure , I will share code soon